# atom git asks to initialize after clone

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I cloned a repo using this command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/me/proj-hope.git .
```

this gave me the expected result (all of my content from GitHub in Atom), except now in the git tab on Atom I am being asked to 'initialize a new project directory'. What does that mean and what do I do? I just want to start pushing and pulling etc off of the project I just cloned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess closing and reopening "refreshes" the project and solves the problem. Is there a refresh button?